# ssl_error_inappropriate_fallback_alert

Tags: https, firefox

Using Firefox got this error: "The server rejected the handshake because the client downgraded to a lower TLS version than the server supports.  (Error code: ssl_error_inappropriate_fallback_alert)"

First fix attempt was to invoke `about:config` and `set security. tls.version.min` to 1, but it was already set to 1.

Maybe I should uninstall/reinstall Firefox?  Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: yes - same issue still trying to solve it. Started noticing sites clocking longer than normal before loading. I was able to access Bank of America (my issue site) from Windows7 safe mode without any issues. Returning to normal mode allowed access one time then nada.

Answer (score 1):

Cache may have been the issue. At the command line I typed `ipcofig /release` then a few seconds later `ipconfig /renew` . That may have been enough.

However, I also typed `ipconfig /dnsflush` . All good after that.

Comment: That's assuming the user is on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was solved when I disabled "SSL scanning" in BitDefender (BD Antivirus Plus 2015). It worked instantly.